# why my Camera associated with game view rotates(0,0,0) as soon as play button in game view is clicked?(is it by default)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

[SC of code associated with camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8fLd.png)

[SC Before Clicking the play button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2kMM.png)

[SC After clicking play button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkSw6.png)

Are any of my setting wrong why can't I see my 3d model after clicking play button and all the camera movements are scripted and applied to "Camera";(

Comment: Actually the objects are still in the Inspector. Is it possible that just your camera is not pointing to them, and when you press play just the objects are behind the camera?

Comment: The camera that I set for game view is "camera" and it is in the position as shown in pic before clicking play button ,how is it that it changes its position  after clicking play button?

Comment: You post in the question that you have some scrips applied to the camera. Does any of this scrips rotate it somehow?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8fLd.png
here is the SC of the code
as u can see the rotation only gets updated as soon as the object starts moving
nut not as soon as I click the play button

Comment: Ok start by commenting out the code you posted, and check the answer I gave you. To see where the camera is pointing at

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the camera shows you the same that you are you seing in Edit Mode by doing this:

- In Edit mode you select what the angle and position you consider (for example what appear in the first image you liked)
- In the inspector you select `Camera`
- In the Editor you select: `GameObject -> Align With View`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXri5QRC3HU

Comment: What about the second camera which appears in the first image? Main Camera is named. Later is is not any more in the second image.

Comment: well I deleted it to make sure it isn't causing the problem!

Comment: did u try to run start the scene with the scrip in the camera commented? And what are you trying to do with that scrip? follow a particular object?